# Same VIP different MAC

Tags: arp, mac-address, oracle-linux

I am observing this behavior on a dual-homed server that is sending traffic in active/active mode on its 2 links connected to the same uplink switch. The server is running [IPMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28993/gfkcy.html) so it generates traffic using the same virtual IP on the 2 different interfaces with different MAC.

Am I configuring the server correctly or am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: If you don't have to change the switch settings, then by logical reasoning, it's expected the MACs will differ, else the switch will get "MAC flapping".